# Calling a (CKEditor) function insertElement() removes the tag contents

Tags: html, ckeditor, emoji

I make a click listener on class '.sticker'. It calls function 'editor.insertElement(eventElement)'.
But this function removes HTML tag contents event occured.

1. In Sticker Panel, click sticker and into listener, then call 'insertSticker'
   [image]
   [image]
2. 'insertSticker' command call function 'insertElement(sticker  tag)'

[image]

3. It goes inside the editor and its img tag disappears from the sticker panel.

[image]
[image]
[image]

**How can I keep the  tag content in the sticker panel after insertElement()?**

Below is the full code. (Customizing CKEditor 'emoji' plugin)

```
/**
 * @license Copyright (c) 2003-2020, CKSource - Frederico Knabben. All rights reserved.
 * For licensing, see LICENSE.md or https://ckeditor.com/legal/ckeditor-oss-license
 */
(function () {
  'use strict';

  var stylesLoaded = false,
      arrTools = CKEDITOR.tools.array,
      htmlEncode = CKEDITOR.tools.htmlEncode,
      EmojiDropdown = CKEDITOR.tools.createClass({
        $: function (editor, plugin) {
          var lang = this.lang = editor.lang.emoji,
              self = this,
              ICON_SIZE = 21;

          this.listeners = [];
          this.plugin = plugin;
          this.editor = editor;
          this.groups = [
            {
              groupName: '1001',
              position: {
                x: -1 * ICON_SIZE,
                y: 0
              },
              items: []
            },
            {
              groupName: '1002',
              position: {
                x: -3 * ICON_SIZE,
                y: -1 * ICON_SIZE
              },
              items: []
            },
            {
              groupName: '1003',
              position: {
                x: -5 * ICON_SIZE,
                y: -2 * ICON_SIZE
              },
              items: []
            }
          ];

          // Keeps html elements references to not find them again.
          this.elements = {};

          // Name is responsible for icon name also.
          editor.ui.add('EmojiPanel', CKEDITOR.UI_PANELBUTTON, {
            label: 'emoji',
            title: lang.title,
            modes: {wysiwyg: 1},
            editorFocus: 0,
            toolbar: 'insert',
            panel: {
              css: [
                CKEDITOR.skin.getPath('editor'),
                plugin.path + 'skins/default.css'
              ],
              attributes: {
                role: 'listbox',
                'aria-label': lang.title
              },
              markFirst: false
            },

            onBlock: function (panel, block) {
              var keys = block.keys,
                  rtl = editor.lang.dir === 'rtl';

              keys[rtl ? 37 : 39] = 'next'; // ARROW-RIGHT
              keys[40] = 'next'; // ARROW-DOWN
              keys[9] = 'next'; // TAB
              keys[rtl ? 39 : 37] = 'prev'; // ARROW-LEFT
              keys[38] = 'prev'; // ARROW-UP
              keys[CKEDITOR.SHIFT + 9] = 'prev'; // SHIFT + TAB
              keys[32] = 'click'; // SPACE

              self.blockElement = block.element;
              self.emojiList = self.editor._.emoji.list;

              self.addEmojiToGroups();

              block.element.getAscendant('html').addClass('cke_emoji');
              block.element.getDocument().appendStyleSheet(
                  CKEDITOR.getUrl(CKEDITOR.basePath + 'contents.css'));
              block.element.addClass('cke_emoji-panel_block');
              block.element.setHtml(self.createEmojiBlock());
              block.element.removeAttribute('title');
              panel.element.addClass('cke_emoji-panel');

              self.items = block._.getItems();

              self.blockObject = block;
              self.elements.emojiItems = block.element.find(
                  '.cke_emoji-outer_emoji_block li > a');
              self.elements.sectionHeaders = block.element.find(
                  '.cke_emoji-outer_emoji_block h2');
              self.elements.input = block.element.findOne('input');
              self.inputIndex = self.getItemIndex(self.items,
                  self.elements.input);
              self.elements.emojiBlock = block.element.findOne(
                  '.cke_emoji-outer_emoji_block');
              self.elements.navigationItems = block.element.find('nav li');
              self.elements.sections = block.element.find('section');
              self.registerListeners();

            },

            onOpen: self.openReset()
          });
        },
        proto: {
          registerListeners: function () {
            arrTools.forEach(this.listeners, function (item) {
              var root = this.blockElement,
                  selector = item.selector,
                  listener = item.listener,
                  event = item.event,
                  ctx = item.ctx || this;

              arrTools.forEach(root.find(selector).toArray(), function (node) {
                node.on(event, listener, ctx);
              });
            }, this);
          },
          createEmojiBlock: function () {
            var output = [];

            output.push(this.createGroupsNavigation());
            output.push(this.createEmojiListBlock());

            return '<div class="cke_emoji-inner_panel">' + output.join('')
                + '</div>';
          },
          createGroupsNavigation: function () {
            var itemTemplate,
                items,
                imgUrl;

            imgUrl = CKEDITOR.getUrl(this.plugin.path + 'assets/iconsall.png');


            itemTemplate = new CKEDITOR.template(
                '<li class="cke_emoji-navigation_item" data-cke-emoji-group="{group}">'
                +
                '<a href="#" draggable="false" _cke_focus="1" title="{group}">'
                +
                '<span style="background-image:url(' + imgUrl + ');' +
                'background-repeat:no-repeat;background-position:{positionX}px {positionY}px;"></span>'
                +
                '</a></li>'
            );

            items = arrTools.reduce(this.groups, function (acc, item) {
              if (!item.items.length) {
                return acc;
              } else {
                return acc + itemTemplate.output({
                  group: htmlEncode(item.groupName),
                  positionX: item.position.x,
                  positionY: item.position.y
                });
              }
            }, '');
            this.listeners.push({
              selector: 'nav',
              event: 'click',
              listener: function (event) {
                console.log("clickEvent = " + JSON.stringify(event.data));
                var activeElement = event.data.getTarget().getAscendant('li',
                    true);
                console.log("activeElement" + JSON.stringify(activeElement));
                if (!activeElement) {
                  return;
                }
                arrTools.forEach(this.elements.navigationItems.toArray(),
                    function (node) {
                      if (node.equals(activeElement)) {
                        node.addClass('active');
                      } else {
                        node.removeClass('active');
                      }
                    });

                this.clearSearchAndMoveFocus(activeElement);

                event.data.preventDefault();
              }
            });

            return '<nav aria-label="' + htmlEncode(this.lang.navigationLabel)
                + '"><ul>' + items + '</ul></nav>';
          },
          createEmojiListBlock: function () {
            var self = this;
            this.listeners.push({
              selector: '.cke_emoji-outer_emoji_block',
              event: 'scroll',
              listener: (function () {
                var buffer = CKEDITOR.tools.throttle(150,
                    self.refreshNavigationStatus, self);
                return buffer.input;
              })()
            });

            this.listeners.push({
              selector: '.sticker',
              event: 'click',
              listener: function (event) {
                this.editor.execCommand('insertSticker', {
                  sticker: event.data.getTarget()
                });
              }
                        });
            return '<div class="cke_emoji-outer_emoji_block">'
                + this.getEmojiSections() + '</div>';
          },
          getEmojiSections: function () {
            return arrTools.reduce(this.groups, function (acc, item) {
              var length = item.items.length;
              // If group is empty skip it.
              if (length == 0) {
                return acc;
              } else {
                return acc + this.getEmojiSection(item);
              }
            }, '', this);
          },
          getEmojiSection: function (item) {
            var groupName = htmlEncode(item.groupName),
                group = this.getEmojiListGroup(item.items);
            return '<section data-cke-emoji-group="' + groupName + '" ><ul>'
                + group + '</ul></section>';
          },
          getEmojiListGroup: function (items) {
            var emojiTpl = new CKEDITOR.template('<li class="cke_emoji-item">' +
                '<img class="sticker" width="120" height="auto" draggable="false" '
                                + 'data-cke-emoji-group="{groupName}" src="{src}"></li>');

            return arrTools.reduce(
                items,
                function (acc, item) {
                  addEncodedName(item);
                  return acc + emojiTpl.output({
                    src: htmlEncode(item.src),
                    groupName: htmlEncode(item.groupName),
                  });
                },
                '',
                this
            );
          },
          openReset: function () {
            // Resets state of emoji dropdown.
            // Clear filters, reset focus, etc.
            var self = this,
                firstCall;

            return function () {

              if (!firstCall) {
                //self.filter( '' );
                firstCall = true;
              }

              self.elements.emojiBlock.$.scrollTop = 0;
              self.refreshNavigationStatus();

              // Reset focus:
              CKEDITOR.tools.setTimeout(function () {
                //self.elements.input.focus(true);
                self.blockObject._.markItem(self.inputIndex);
              }, 0, self);
            };
          },
          refreshNavigationStatus: function () {
            var containerOffset = this.elements.emojiBlock.getClientRect().top,
                section,
                groupName;

            section = arrTools.filter(this.elements.sections.toArray(),
                function (element) {
                  var rect = element.getClientRect();
                  if (!rect.height) {
                    return false;
                  }
                  return rect.height + rect.top > containerOffset;
                });
            groupName = section.length ? section[0].data('cke-emoji-group')
                : false;

            arrTools.forEach(this.elements.navigationItems.toArray(),
                function (node) {
                  if (node.data('cke-emoji-group') === groupName) {
                    node.addClass('active');
                  } else {
                    node.removeClass('active');
                  }
                });
          },
          clearSearchAndMoveFocus: function (activeElement) {
            this.moveFocus(activeElement.data('cke-emoji-group'));
          },
          moveFocus: function (groupName) {
            var firstSectionItem = this.blockElement.findOne(
                'a[data-cke-emoji-group="' + htmlEncode(groupName) + '"]'),
                itemIndex;

            if (!firstSectionItem) {
              return;
            }

            itemIndex = this.getItemIndex(this.items, firstSectionItem);
            firstSectionItem.focus(true);
            firstSectionItem.getAscendant('section').getFirst().scrollIntoView(
                true);
            this.blockObject._.markItem(itemIndex);
          },
          getItemIndex: function (nodeList, item) {
            return arrTools.indexOf(nodeList.toArray(), function (element) {
              return element.equals(item);
            });
          },
          addEmojiToGroups: function () {
            var groupObj = {};
            arrTools.forEach(this.groups, function (group) {
              groupObj[group.groupName] = group.items;
            }, this);

            arrTools.forEach(this.emojiList, function (emojiObj) {
              groupObj[emojiObj.groupName].push(emojiObj);
            }, this);
          }
        }
      });

  CKEDITOR.plugins.add('emoji', {
    requires: 'ajax,panelbutton,floatpanel',
    lang: 'en', // %REMOVE_LINE_CORE%
    icons: 'emojipanel',
    hidpi: true,

    isSupportedEnvironment: function () {
      return !CKEDITOR.env.ie || CKEDITOR.env.version >= 11;
    },

    beforeInit: function () {
      if (!this.isSupportedEnvironment()) {
        return;
      }
      if (!stylesLoaded) {
        CKEDITOR.document.appendStyleSheet(this.path + 'skins/default.css');
        stylesLoaded = true;
      }
    },

    init: function (editor) {
      if (!this.isSupportedEnvironment()) {
        return;
      }

      var stickerListUrl = '/sticker';

      CKEDITOR.ajax.load(CKEDITOR.getUrl(stickerListUrl), function (data) {
        if (data === null) {
          return;
        }
        if (editor._.emoji === undefined) {
          editor._.emoji = {};
        }

        if (editor._.emoji.list === undefined) {
          editor._.emoji.list = JSON.parse(data);
        }
      });

      editor.addCommand('insertSticker', {
        exec: function (editor, data) {
          console.log("data = " + JSON.stringify(data));
          editor.insertElement(data.sticker);
        }
      });

      if (editor.plugins.toolbar) {
        new EmojiDropdown(editor, this);
      }

    }
  });

  function addEncodedName(item) {
    if (!item.name) {
      item.name = htmlEncode(
          item.id.replace(/::.*$/, ':').replace(/^:|:$/g, ''));
    }
    return item;
  }
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this problem.

Function of insertElement(HTML Element) is move a original element.

So, first i copy element to other variable. and call insertElement(Clone HTML Element).

So, original element remain.